# gRPC and ExtensionRegistry

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using gRPC with Java, and the messages that I'm sending may contain extensions. In the [Protobuf docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#extension) they say:

```
When parsing a message that might have extensions, you must provide an ExtensionRegistry in which you have registered any extensions that you want to be able to parse.
```

The question is how I specify the `ExtensionRegistry` in the code which uses gRPC as a client (and the message parsing is performed inside the gRPC-generated code).

**UPDATE: support for extensions was added to gRPC**

```
ProtoLiteUtils.setExtensionRegistry()
```

A note from the developer: *This API is not stable, and will very likely change once we have a more appropriate long term solution (with custom registries per method, etc.)*

[more info](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/grpc-io/fk-o9qrXTV0/pppJmG2bBwAJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I can't find anything about ExtensionRegistry in the GRPC code. It's possible that because extensions were removed in proto3, GRPC chose not to support them even if you are using proto2.

However, as a work-around, you can always serialize your proto and then parse it again:

```
message = MyType.parseFrom(message.toByteString(),
                           myExtensionRegistry);
```

This wastes a bunch of resources to serialize and re-parse, but should get the job done. (This, of course, relies on unknown field preservation, another feature that was removed in proto3, but you're using proto2, so it should work!)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! Do you think it would be better to start using "Any" type instead of extensions, as, to my understanding, it should be in `proto3`? For example, performance-wise.

Comment: Another thought - may I cause the gRPC return the `ByteString` directly, without it doing the initial parsing, and then moving to byte string -> parsing again?

Comment: Extensions are a better fit for the Protobuf wire format and therefore will be more efficient in many cases, but given that the Protobuf project is moving away from them, it's probably prudent to use "Any" in new projects. (Note: I originally designed the "extensions" feature but no longer work for Google, so I may be biased.) I don't know if gRPC lets you request a raw ByteString -- that seems like a reasonable feature but never having used gRPC myself I couldn't say if they allow it.

Comment: I see, thanks :) Conceptually I find advantages with both approaches: with `Any` we can do a "delayed parsing", so it is useful when some of the information can be added to a Message by external code, without the "core" message "knowing" it in advance. On the other hand, `Extensions` are useful when, for example, I can have multiple instances of same extension type - I can just identify them by the ID (say, "mono image", "left", "right"); with `Any` same construct would be more complex to represent.
Anyway, thanks again for the answer, this definitely help me to make progress with it.

Comment: Just FYI: the support for extensions was just [committed](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/grpc-io/fk-o9qrXTV0/pppJmG2bBwAJ) to gRPC, so this makes things simpler for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ProtoLiteUtils.setExtensionRegistry](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/702518af22a22ed192a8f0f7682bd6f1fc753a65/protobuf-lite/src/main/java/io/grpc/protobuf/lite/ProtoLiteUtils.java#L73) which was recently added and will be available in the 0.14 release.

Comment: Yes, you have answered me on that in the "grpc.io" group :) I have posted an update on this question right away. Thanks again.